# Calling data with a condition PDO droplist

Tags: php, pdo

In my db, a column named 'stocksInDate' contains Y-m-d g:ia 
How do I call data within the past 30days only?

```
<select name="openBooks"><option value="">-- Select A Book --</option>

foreach ($my_connection->query("SELECT col1 FROM books_db WHERE exec_datetime >= DATE_SUB(stocksInDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY) LIMIT 4") as $row){
        echo("</option><option value=". $row['col1'] . ">". $row['col1'] ."</option>");
        };
```

Comment: what you are getting now?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: you cant loop a mysqli query object,you have to fetch the data from queryy object and loop it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
exec_datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(stocksInDate, 'your format'),INTERVAL '30' DAY)
```

For changing format of date:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Also get your query result in a new variable and add var to foreach like:-

```
    $rows = $my_connection->query("SELECT col1 FROM books_db WHERE exec_datetime >= DATE_SUB(stocksInDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY) LIMIT 4");

if(check num rows > 0) 
    foreach($rows as $row)
```

Comment: I want to calculate 30 days against 'stocksInDate'. Not against the current date.

Comment: then change NOW() to stocksInDate

Comment: Hi Rakesh... I'm getting this error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: first check your query result ? print_r($rows); your query passing wrong result

Comment: It works without this section.  WHERE exec_datetime >= DATE_SUB(stocksInDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY)

Comment: you need to use dateformat to match your db date check updated

Comment: WHERE exec_datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(stocksInDate, 'Y-m-d g:ia'),INTERVAL '30' DAY)

Comment: this will be like DATE_FORMAT(stocksInDate, '%Y-%m-%d g:ia') and for more check link added in answer

Comment: THanks. THis is the date format in the db '2012-11-18 4:52pm'  I used this code but not working?  exec_datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(stocksInDate, '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i%p'),INTERVAL '30' DAY)  What might be the issue?

Comment: check your db field and sended formated values is same?

Comment: Thanks. Yes the field names & table names are correct.

Comment: my mean field values format both table field and sending format

Comment: Thanks Rakesh... I got it sorted. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Your welcome dude :) you can upvote or accept answer found helpful:)